# C++ access function from C DLL/lib

Tags: c++, c, dll, static-libraries

I'm desperately trying to access a DLL supplied with some hardware. I have the DLL, the LIB file and the headers for the DLL.

I first tried using C# but failed due to the large data structures that are passed around. I got the functions called but the values in the structures that are modified are not correct.

I then thought about writing a wrapper class in C++ and use this as a library for C#. But again here I can call the function but if I tested an signed long that is passed it is "1072955392l" instead of "-1l".

I then just renamed the cpp file to ".c" and compiled it again. Now I get the correct value.

Are there some differences in the datatypes from C to C++?

The functions for the LIb in the supplied include file are declared like that:

```
_declspec (dllimport) long ResetControl(Registers* regs);
```

I compile using VS2013:

```
cl test.cpp /link test.lib
cl test.c /link test.lib
```

The cpp file and c file are the same unless I needed to include #include  for the cpp and wrap the dll include header in

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "test.h"
}
```

The test.c file looks like:

```
//#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "test.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  Registers Regs;
  Reset (&Regs); 
  printf ("Value: %dl\n\r", Regs.Product);
  return 0;
}
```

The C++ file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include "test.h"
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  Registers Regs;
  Reset (&Regs);
  printf ("Value: %dl\n\r", Regs.Product);
  return 0;
}
```

Both compile, but the result of printing Regs.Products is different:

```
C: -1l
C++: 1072955392l
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing that I can see, what does the "test.h" file look like?

Comment: You could check the assembly output (`cl /Fa`) of both C and C++ versions, then compare them.

Comment: Also, if you're using `long` integers, just to be sure you should at least use the `%ld` format before the `l` instead of just `%d`.

Comment: checking the assembly output I recognized that sizes for the structure were different when compiling with C or C++. The size of BOOL for the Lib seems to be a 4 byte type. Now I got it working with C++. Using that knowledge I fired up the C# project again and corrected the sizes of the structures. But still no look here :(

Answer (score 0):

I saw somewhere that there is a matter of **aligning to 4 bytes** while compiling the client of the DLL.

However have a look to those pages:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21/Beginner-s-Tutorial-Calling-Visual-Basic-ActiveX-D
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6242/Step-by-Step-Calling-C-DLLs-from-VC-and-VB-Part

Alexandre